# what is relation between the image of the closure of the unit disk and the closure of the image of the unit disk under an analytic function?

Tags: complex-analysis

what is relation between the image of the closure of the unit disk and the closure of the image of the unit disk under an analytic function?  That is what is the relation between $f(\overline U)$ and $\overline{f(U)}$.

Comment: So what are your thoughts? Can you prove any inclusions?

Comment: can we find any inclusion relation?

Comment: If you haven't tried to find inclusion relations, I think you should. If you have tried, you should tell us what you tried so we can help you better!

Comment: $f(\overline U) \subset \overline{f(U)}$ .Is it correct?

Comment: How did you come to that guess? Have you tried to prove it? If so, how did you try to prove it?

Comment: Since f is analytic in U, the set $f(\overline U)$ is bounded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's first try to see if the inclusion $f(\overline{U})\subset \overline{f(U)}$ is true. How do we check this? We must take a point $z\in f(\overline{U})$, and then see if it also belongs to the set $\overline{f(U)}$. If $z\in f(\overline{U})$, this means that $z = f(w)$ for some $w\in \overline{U}$. Since $w\in \overline{U}$, this means there exists a sequence of points $w_n\in U$ such that $\lim_{n\to \infty}w_n = w$. Therefore $$z = f(w) = f\left(\lim_{n\to\infty} w_n\right) = \lim_{n\to\infty}f(w_n),$$ where the last equality is valid because $f$ is continuous.

*WARNING:* The last equality would not necessarily be true if $f$ were not continuous. But it's ok for us, because analytic functions are continuous.

Now, since $w_n\in U$ we have by definition that $f(w_n)\in f(U)$. We have therefore proved that $z$ is a limit of points in $f(U)$. This says exactly that $z\in \overline{f(U)}$. This proves that $f(\overline{U})\subset\overline{f(U)}$.

Now what about the inclusion $\overline{f(U)}\subset f(\overline{U})$? We try to prove this in the same way: take a point $z\in \overline{f(U)}$, and check to see if it also lies in $f(\overline{U})$. The fact that $z\in \overline{f(U)}$ means by definition that there is a sequence of points $w_n\in U$ such that $z = \lim_{n\to\infty}f(w_n)$. Unfortunately, we don't know that the sequence $w_n$ converges. But, by Bolzano-Weierstrass, we know there is a subsequence $w_{n_k}$ that *does* converge, say to some point $w$. Moreover, since $w$ is a limit of points $w_{n_k}$ that lie in $U$, we see that $w\in\overline{U}$. Thus $$z = \lim_{n\to \infty} f(w_n) = \lim_{k\to \infty}f(w_{n_k}) = f\left(\lim_{k\to \infty}w_{n_k}\right) = f(w).$$ Again, just like above, the second to last inequality only holds because $f$ is continuous. Since $w\in \overline{U}$ and $z = f(w)$, it follows that $z\in f(\overline{U})$. This proves that $\overline{f(U)}\subset f(\overline{U})$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: Can we take this as $f(\overline U)=\overline{f(U)}$?